# Handling post on dynamic row on a html table with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a dynamic table that I will be submitted to database.

The html is looked like this :

```
<form id="upload">
   <div class="box-body">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
             <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                  <table class="table table-hover" id="tableReport">
                      <thead>
                        <th>TYPE</th>
                        <th>ITEM</th>
                        <th>DAMAGE</th>
                        <th>REPAIR</th>
                        <th>REMARKS</th>
                        <th>MANHOUR</th>
                        <th><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="addRow" type="button">ADD</button></th>
                      </thead>

                      <tbody>
                         <!--GENERATED BY JQUERY-->
                      </tbody>
                   </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.box-body -->

   <div class="box-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Upload</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

See, on my `<th>`, I have a button with id `addRow` that have a function to add a row on a last row.
This is the code :

```
$(document).on('click', '#addRow', function () {
        var selType = '<select class="form-control" name="type">';
        var selItem = '<select class="form-control" name="item">';
        var selDamage = '<select class="form-control" name="damage">';
        var selRepair = '<select class="form-control" name="repair">';
        $.each(<?php echo json_encode($type); ?>, function (i, elem) {
            selType += '<option>' + elem.NAMA_TYPE + '</option>';
        });

        $.each(<?php echo json_encode($item); ?>, function (i, elem) {
            selItem += '<option>' + elem.NAMA_ITEM + '</option>';
        });

        $.each(<?php echo json_encode($damage_codes); ?>, function (i, elem) {
            selDamage += '<option>' + elem.NAMA_DAMAGE + '</option>';

        });

        $.each(<?php echo json_encode($repair_codes); ?>, function (i, elem) {
            selRepair += '<option>' + elem.NAMA_REPAIR + '</option>';
        });

        selType += '</select>';
        selItem += '</select>';
        selDamage += '</select>';
        selRepair += '</select>';

        $("#tableReport").find('tbody').append('<tr><td>' + selType +
                '</td><td>' + selItem +
                '</td><td>' + selDamage +
                '</td><td>' + selRepair +
                '</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control name="remarks" placeholder="Describe it..">' +
                '</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control time" name="manhour">' +
                '</td><td><button class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Delete</button>' +
                '</td></tr>');
        $(".time").inputmask("hh:mm");

    });
```

Now, this is the problem. How to handling the `form`. When `<button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Upload</button>` is clicked to submit, I will handled it use jquery ajax. The code looked like this

```
$(document).on('submit', '#upload', function(){
  /*First, How to handled the dynamic row ?? */
  /* Commonly, I use var aVar = $('selector').val(); */
  /* Ex, I have two rows, How bout to handle two select option in different row ?*/

  $.ajax({
           url: 'LINK TO CHECK THE POST if has SUBMITTED',
           type: 'POST',
           data : {/*dynamic row that will be passed : data*/}
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(obj) {   
       })
  return false;
});
```

How can I handle that dynamic row, and how can I debug if the post have success ?

**UPDATED**

This code to check the condition of a ship container. If a container have many damage, it will be representated with one row as one damage. If the container have 3 damage, it will be have 3 rows. I want to submit it on a table in my database in tbl_damage_detail. I have plan to multiple insert. So, I Imagine to store that rows into an array. with foreach, I will be inserted them.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f4jpdnjd/)

Answer (score 0):

If the inputs are added correctly to the form you just need to submit the form with AJAX, no need for anything special, one way is to use the jQuery `serialize()` method like this.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#upload', function(event){
  $.ajax({
           url: 'LINK TO CHECK THE POST if has SUBMITTED',
           type: 'POST',
           data : $(this).serialize(),
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(obj) {   
       })
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

with your code,i really don't know what you want to do .

first, "on" is used to bind event with dynamic dom ,but id=addRow is not a dynamic dom,it is unnecessary to use on

```
"$(document).on('click', '#addRow', function () {"
```

just use `$("#addRow").click( function () {...})`

and then, `<form id="upload">`, i am not sure you have decide to post date to service with submit, in fact ,here is a dynamic table ,if you use submit to post your data ,it may complex with your whole table data .(using submit , input must set the name tag)

i suggest you should handle each row data

```
//get every row data
var tableData = [] ; 
$("#tableReport tbody tr").each( function(){
    var tr = &(this);
    var text2 = tr.find(".time").val(); //should use more clean tag
    var data = {test2:test2}//...
    tableData.push(data)
    //use ajax with the data
});
//next handle the tableData with ajax
```

this scene is very fat to mvvm like: angular , vue.js or avalon.js ,use one of them,with more clean but less code .

Comment: Thanks. Btw, this code to check the condition of a ship container. If a container have many damage, it will be representated with one row as one damage. If the container have 3 damage, it will be have 3 rows. I want to submit it on a table in my database in tbl_damage_detail. I have plan to multiple insert. So, I Imagine to store that rows into an array. with foreach, I will be inserted them.